# JavaScript return false is not stopping other functions from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation, return

I have a few JS functions that are running upon clicking the "save" button on a page. The button looks like this:

```
<img src="images/btn/save.gif" name="btnSubmit" onClick="noSpaceTest();minMaxValues();compare2dates(benefit_start_date, benefit_end_date,'javascript:saveNewBenefit()')" width="60" height="22" border="0" class="btnimg">
```

The function I'm interested in is minMaxValues(). If this test fails, the form should not submit (which in this case means none of the other functions should run.) I used return false; in the minMaxValues() function, and it runs (warning of a bad value) but after dismissing the alert, the other functions are being called, rather than **stopping**.

Here is the function:

```
//Function to validate if maximum benefit value is more the minimum benefit value
function minMaxValues(){
    var maxAmt = ($('#maxAmount').val());
    var minAmt = ($('#minAmount').val());
    if ((minAmt != '') && (maxAmt != '')){
        try{
            maxAmt = parseInt(maxAmt);
            minAmt = parseInt(minAmt);
                if(maxAmt < minAmt) {
                    alert('The maximum benefit amount must be larger than the minimum amount.');
                return false;
            }
        }catch(e){
            return false;
        }
    }//end maxAmt minAmt comparison
    return true;
}//end minMaxValues function
```

Is there a way to **not** permit any further functions from executing if this one returns false?

Comment: Note, this wouldn't be an issue if you didn't have a whole freaking script in your onclick.  :)  If you called a single function that returned false on failure, everything would work just fine -- and be more readable besides.

Comment: @cHao I couldn't agree with you more. I am working with legacy code that goes **way** back and with a team, so I'm severely limited in what I can/can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"btnSubmit" onClick="noSpaceTest();minMaxValues()?:return;compare2dates(benefit_start_date, benefit_end_date,'javascript:saveNewBenefit()')" width="60" height="22" border="0" class="btnimg">
```

or

```
"btnSubmit" onClick="noSpaceTest();if(!minMaxValues()){return};compare2dates(benefit_start_date, benefit_end_date,'javascript:saveNewBenefit()')" width="60" height="22" border="0" class="btnimg">
```

should stop the submit as well as stopping the other functions from executing

*edit:* You should really put it all in a cleaner click handler function, this is just a quick fix

Comment: haha, no problem can you confirm that the code I have up there right now works? i did edit it a couple times after I first posted

Comment: @dihakz its better to encapsulate your logic inside a function, and have this function called if your button is clicked. Look at Maciej's  answer. 

Its a lot cleaner.

Comment: @stackErr is right, it would be best if your onclick called a single function

Comment: @Stephan who would you prefer I 'award' the answer to? In my case, this was the preferred solution (quicker and easier bug fix) even though the other is more of a "best practice"

Comment: @Stephan I forgot to comment: yes, it is working as it is written now. However, the original way it was written (below) worked better since it still threw up an alert (and so is the one I am using.) `if(!minMaxValues()){return};`

Comment: kk i'll add it as an alternate in the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function that encapsulates your logic:

```
function clickHandler()
{
     noSpaceTest();
     var minMax = minMaxValues();
     if(minMax)
     {
         compare2dates(benefit_start_date, benefit_end_date,'javascript:saveNewBenefit()')
     }
}
```

then

```
<img src="images/btn/save.gif" name="btnSubmit" onClick="clickHandler();" width="60" height="22" border="0" class="btnimg">
```

Comment: This is certainly the most 'correct' and cleaner solution. Unfortunately the scripts are external and I can't modify it there, only on execution.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function chuma()
{
noSpaceTest();
if(minMaxValues())
compare2dates(benefit_start_date, benefit_end_date,'javascript:saveNewBenefit()');
}
</script>
<img src="images/btn/save.gif" name="btnSubmit" onClick="chuma();" width="60" height="22" border="0" class="btnimg">
```

This will work.I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of return false, just try return. Return false still returns a value to be evaluated, while return just exits the function. Edit: maybe try a callback function instead of return.

Comment: This is definitely something I need to explore further. Thank you for the recommendation.